# iOS - plist file parsing error

Tags: iphone

The application gives error as soon as I put `&` in the string value of one of the elements in my plist file. Any idea why?

```
<plist>
    <array>
        <string>http://www.foo.com?a=b&c=d</string>
    </array>
</plist>
```

If I remove this `&` in URL, everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to replace the `&` by `&amp;`

Answer (score 2):

Replace `&` with `&amp;` It should be the problem I hope!